# I own an LLC, how should I go about contributing to a 401(k)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, limited-liability-company, retirement-plan

I am one of two LLC members - we have been operating for about 2 years.  We have no employees.  I would like to start a 401(k) and contribute as much as I can to it.

We don't have salaries currently, we just take draws.  After I set up the 401(k) account, how can I contribute the maximum amount?  Can I pay myself a salary($1500/month) and put 100% of each paycheck in the 401(k)?  Is this the correct approach to minimize my tax burden?

USA, California

Comment: Have you considered a SEP? That is trivial to set up. It also has higher contribution limits.

Comment: 401(k) plans have higher limits actually, because the employee can contribute $18K and then the company can additionally contribute up to 25% of profit.  A SEP is, in effect, just the company part of the 401(k).

Answer (score 1):

It's the correct approach, but not the correct mechanism. As a partner in a partnership, you do not get salary and instead you get "guaranteed payments".

Since it is a partnership and not a sole-proprietorship, solo-401k is not an option. I suggest you engage a licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in your State) to help you set this up. Generally, EA is "[Enrolled Agent](https://www.irs.gov/Tax-Professionals/Enrolled-Agents/Enrolled-Agent-Information)", but in this case it can also be "[Enrolled Actuary](https://www.irs.gov/Tax-Professionals/Enrolled-Actuaries/Enrolled-Actuary-Information)".

Comment: according to the information on the Vangaurd website (https://investor.vanguard.com/what-we-offer/small-business/individual-401k) it says the following may participate: "Sole proprietors or partners who have no
common-law employees."  I feel like my business falls into that category, right?

Comment: @shirefriendship I would really not know... I suggest asking a professional. This is out of scope for *personal* finance.